# EXPLAIN Shows "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY" and very slow after migrating from MariaDB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was migrating from my old MariaDB 10.0 database to new Google Cloud Sql with Mysql 5.7 with mysqldump method. After migrating, i got some very slow query regarding with WHERE EXISTS statement.

I tried to EXPLAIN my query on both my old DB and new DB and it explained different result. Since it using dump, i am assuming that no changes with the table indexes. This is the query that i wanted to run

```
SELECT * FROM detitem
    where exists (select 1 from detlayanan
                    where detitem.iddetlayanan = detlayanan.id
                      and detlayanan.layanan_idlayanan='LYN15176176101503')
```

the EXPLAIN from old DB

```
+------+-------------+------------+------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys                      | key                        | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+------------+------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | detlayanan | ref  | PRIMARY,fk_detlayanan_layanan1_idx | fk_detlayanan_layanan1_idx | 22      | const                          | 11030 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | detitem    | ref  | FK_detitem_detlayanan              | FK_detitem_detlayanan      | 52      | citridia_sinadme.detlayanan.id |     1 |                          |
+------+-------------+------------+------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

and the EXPLAIN from new DB

```
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                      | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | detitem    | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 2079094 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | detlayanan | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fk_detlayanan_layanan1_idx | PRIMARY | 52      | citridia_sinadme.detitem.iddetlayanan |       1 |     5.00 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

The new one is doing Full-table scan even there is index exist. Am i missing something here?

Here is the "detlayanan" table

```
CREATE TABLE `detlayanan` (
  `transaksi_idtransaksi` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `layanan_idlayanan` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `nama_layanan` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jumlah_beli` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `harga` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `hargatotal` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `luas_p` double(255,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `luas_l` double(255,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `luas_q` double(255,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `keterangan` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `iddeposit` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posisi` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `idworkshop` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_wsot` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `total_bersih` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `total_min_order` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `kondisi_barang` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_detlayanan_layanan1_idx` (`layanan_idlayanan`),
  KEY `fk_detlayanan_deposit` (`iddeposit`),
  KEY `transaksi_idtransaksi` (`transaksi_idtransaksi`),
  CONSTRAINT `detlayanan_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`transaksi_idtransaksi`) REFERENCES `transaksi` (`idtransaksi`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_detlayanan_layanan1` FOREIGN KEY (`layanan_idlayanan`) REFERENCES `layanan` (`idlayanan`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

And here is the "detitem" table

```
CREATE TABLE `detitem` (
  `item_iditem` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `layanan_idlayanan` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `jumlah_item` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaksi_idtransaksi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `iddetlayanan` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `hapus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_detitem_item` (`item_iditem`),
  KEY `FK_detitem_layanan` (`layanan_idlayanan`),
  KEY `FK_detitem_transaksi` (`transaksi_idtransaksi`),
  KEY `FK_detitem_detlayanan` (`iddetlayanan`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_detitem_detlayanan` FOREIGN KEY (`iddetlayanan`) REFERENCES `detlayanan` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_detitem_item` FOREIGN KEY (`item_iditem`) REFERENCES `item` (`iditem`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_detitem_layanan` FOREIGN KEY (`layanan_idlayanan`) REFERENCES `layanan` (`idlayanan`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_detitem_transaksi` FOREIGN KEY (`transaksi_idtransaksi`) REFERENCES `transaksi` (`idtransaksi`)
)
```

I expect the "rows" on explain stay small, in the old DB, "rows" stays at very low even in another table. but in the new DB it can shows up to million.

**UPDATE**

After some research, actually i must explicitly add some indexed column in the where statement to accompany EXISTS statement. so the query would be like this

```
SELECT  * FROM  detitem WHERE
    <indexed column> in (<some id's>)
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM detlayanan WHERE detitem.iddetlayanan = 
    detlayanan.id AND detlayanan.layanan_idlayanan = 'LYN15176176101503' )
```

apparently MySQL doing full scan on detitem table to check the subquery values is exists or not, when some indexed column are declared, sql does not need to did that. Also this case were found in MySQL.

some references:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/exists-to-in-optimization/

Comment: My first guess is that in fact the indices have changed.  In any case, you need to show us the indices from both databases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 
Is the index from the example table above enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case where MariaDB's Optimizer is a step or two ahead of MySQL's.

See if this works well:

```
SELECT  i.*
    FROM ( SELECT  id
            FROM  detlayanan
            WHERE  layanan_idlayanan = 'LYN15176176101503' 
         ) AS x
    JOIN  detitem AS i  ON x.id = i.iddetlayanan
```

I *think* it will work well in both servers.

Simpler yet:

```
SELECT  i.*
    FROM  detlayanan AS lay
    JOIN  detitem AS i  ON lay.id = i.iddetlayanan 
    WHERE  lay.layanan_idlayanan = 'LYN15176176101503'
```

Comment: I know, JOIN would be far quicker than EXISTS. i forgot to mention that query above was generated by laravel "whereHas" function. Aside from that, is there any MySQL query execution plan behaves like MariaDB?

Comment: @Alkaaf - Sorry, I don't know the mappings from whereHas (etc) to SQL in order to reverse-engineer what you are looking for.  (Nor do I know the mappings of the other hundred packages that "simplify" SQL access for the user.  But it does appear that most fail to scale beyond trivial-sized datasets.)